# nginx - how to count number of request hit on nginx server

Tags: nginx, ab-testing

I am new to nginx

I am using nginx for split a/b testing. i am routing to same url but with different cookies. i need to count number of request came to nginx. ex :

3/10 request i will set cookie "a"
7/10 request i will set cookie "b"

for this i need to keep tack of number of requests.

I tried https://github.com/theromis/ngx_counter_zone  . but not able to include this module into nginx.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using nginx i wrote a npm module with express.js which will use cookies based on traffic and using that you can do split-ab testing / ab testing. [npm-ab-testing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-ab-testing)